# Select2 - Object does not support the method

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime-error, jquery-ui-multiselect

I've downloaded JQuery select2 library, in order to use its Multiselect (looks like tags).
I have an MVC application, framework 4.5, and I'm also using bootstrap.
I've tried all kind of solutions, but out of some reason, my application falls on

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'select2'

Here's what I'v tried: 
1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var test = $('#test');
        $(test).select2({
            data: [
                { id: 0, text: "enhancement" },
                { id: 1, text: "bug" },
                { id: 2, text: "duplicate" },
                { id: 3, text: "invalid" },
                { id: 4, text: "wontfix" }
            ],
            multiple: true,
            width: "300px"
        });
    });

<input type="text" id="test" />
```

That's according to: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2rWcG/1/)

2) `$(document).ready(function () { $("#test").select2(); });`

```
                                    <select id="test" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                        <option value="XX">blabla</option>
                                    </select>
```

That's according to: [JQuery page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) (Under Multi-Value Select Boxes, the one under Multiple select types)

I've tried some more which I can't remember, since I've been working on it for a day or so...

My References are to

```
select2.css
select2-bootstrap.css
bootstrap.css
jquery-1.10.2.js
select2.js
bootstrap.js
```

(In that order)
The JQuery Select2 version is 3.5.1
I also tried using jquery-2.1.1.js instead of jquery-1.10.2.js, but it didn't work (same error).

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does that jsFiddle link work for you? It appears to work for me in Chrome. I am assuming you are using IE?

Comment: It works on FireFox too

Comment: Are you binding select2 to <asp:DropDownList /> ?

Comment: jsFiddle works for me in both Chrome and IE.
My application runs on IE 11

Comment: No, Henri, I'm not. As you can see, in the first example the options are binded through jquery into a text field, and in the second one I have a select element with options.

Comment: Do you happen to have Avast On-line Security extension in your IE? That might cause some problem with local javascript files. If you do, try to disable it.

Comment: Nope, no such an add-on... I also tried to run my application in Chrome, and it didn't work, so I doubt it's that kind of a problem...

Comment: First, you don't have a link to jquery that's causing the error see console for that, secondly, why not use Razor to generate token for you from the server and just `$(test).select2()` in jquery!

Plus I think that the element has to be select in order for select2 to function properly